# Convert stringbuilder objects to double

Tags: c#, double, stringbuilder, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a calculator, which is capable of doing line calculations like the windows calculator.

To call my calculation function I try to use a stringbuilder. Everytime for instance 5 is pressed I use

Class declarations:

```
 StringBuilder ccSb = new StringBuilder();
 double ccSub = 0;
 String ccOutput = "";
```

---

```
ccSb.Append("5");
ccSub = Convert.ToDouble(ccSb);
ccOutput = Rechner.rechnen(ccSub, ccCurrentOp, ccOperatorPressed);
```

However the Convert.ToDouble throws the exception that the

> Stringbuilder object is not convertable to System.IConvertible.

Is there any workaround or any other way to get the pressed numbers and save them into a double?

Comment: Use `ccSb.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringBuilder` cannot be directly converted to double but a `String` can. so i suggest you to do like the following:

```
ccSub = Convert.ToDouble(ccSb.ToString());
```